# ArangoDB 2.8 - sort by subquery result - failure

Tags: performance, sorting, arangodb

After move to 2.8 this simple query now froze server with 100% CPU usage ~10sec. In 2.7 (~30ms)

```
FOR P In Person
   LET EventLast = (
    FOR E In Event FILTER E.owner == P._id SORT E.date desc LIMIT 1 RETURN E.date
   )
SORT EventLast[0]
LIMIT 40
RETURN { _id: P._id, name:P.name }
```

Collection Event have skiplist index in `date` and hash index on `owner`

Without "SORT E.date desc" or "SORT EventLast[0]" - 1ms

Comment: Could you also share the approximate number of documents in both `Person` and `Event` plus the reported hash index selectivity? That will allow for a better comparison with 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: Person - 1000
Event - 10000

Comment: Event.owner - hash index selectivity 14.4%


P.S. I never see before 100% usage with ArangoDb, also on more complex queries without indexes. Max 0.5-0.9 sec, but this query turn database to zombie on 8-10sec

Comment: The high CPU load is due to the query doing 1,000 (outer loop) * 10,000 (inner loop) document lookups and filter operations, 10,000,000 in total. That's quite some work for the CPU to do. With the correct index (hash in this case), the number of ops will go down to approximately 1,000 (outer loop) * 1 / 0.14 (inner loop) plus the sort. That should result in less than 30,000 internal ops in total, which is some orders of magnitude faster. As mentioned in my answer, a fix has been committed and will be included in the release following beta2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query optimizer in 2.8-beta picked the skiplist index on `date` for the inner subquery. This index allows removing the `SORT` clause, but the inner query still needs to scan the entire index in reverse order until the first filter match. It does that as many times as there are documents in `Person`.

The 2.7 optimizer instead picked the hash index on `owner` and used a post-index-`SORT`. This was probably better in this case if the number of matches per index lookup is very small, but will be bad if the filter is very unselective.

The 2.8 optimizer will now again prefer the potentially more selective hash index for the inner query. A fix for this has been made today in the `2.8` branch, which will turn into a beta3 or rc (note that there will be a beta2 soon that won't yet contain the fix).